# publicating using php facebook api creates only permalink insted of post on facewall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using PHP facebook API 3.2.3 to connect to facebook and publicate messages from my page.

Until recently it was working find, but now messages are not publicated.
When i copy returned by FB message ID to create link, it is there, but not on my facewall.

I can accesss to my message by link like this:

https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=800134770033938&id=659754124150164

It says, that i've publicated link on my fanpage, but it is not visible on wall.
Ofcourse there are all necessary permissions.

Code looks like this:

```
$fb_fanpage_name = $fb['FBFanpageName'];
$fb_access_token = $fb['FBAccessToken'];
$fb_app_id = $fb['FBApp'];
$fb_secret = $fb['FBSecret'];

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => TRUE,

));

$post = array(
    'access_token' => $fb_access_token,
    'link' => $fb_url
);

try
{
    $res = $facebook->api('/' . $fb_fanpage_name . '/links', 'post', $post);
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    $this->zp($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to FB API on page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/links/ - you can't posting links like this.

Apparently You want post message to feed. 
So to do this try :

```
$post = array(
    'access_token' => $fb_access_token,
    'link' => $fb_url,
    'message' => 'try me!'
);
    $facebook->api('/'. $fb_fanpage_name .'/feed', 'POST', $post);
```

---

Update : to find this look at page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem.

Changing /links to /feed worked. But it was working fine till recently, so it looks like some recent change in facebook. I was looking for quite some time looking for something more complicated :)